# Using the percent notation when calculating height for elements of parent without height

Tags: html, css

I don't want to set `body`'s height explicitely and set child `div`s' height in percents.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <div style="height:10%">
        fdjfdkjl
    </div>
    <div style="height:90%">
        dsds
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this doesn't work. Why? In the specs there is description of behavior:

> When the percent notation is used height of the element is calculated
>   relatively to height of the parent. If the parent is doesn't set
>   explicitely the browser's window is used.

Okay, I can set 100% to the `body`, but this is doesn't work too: its height is just wrapping the content. Why browser's window is not used?

Comment: try `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MattK said,

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

solves the problem. I think this approach works because `div`s' and `body`'s parents have defined sizes. `html` hasn't a parent and the window's `height` is used.